# copy html as string to visual studio 2017

Tags: html, visual-studio, copy-paste

i'm writing html in visual code.
example:

```
<header>
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Customer Name: 0</h1>
  <h2 style="text-align: center">Year: 2001 ,month: 12</h2>
  <h3 style="text-align: center">Total price: 100</h3>
</header>
```

and I want to copy paste the code to visual studio 2017

but in visual studio is look like:

```
  "<header>
  < h1 style = "text-align: center" > Customer Name: 0 </ h1 >

       < h2 style = "text-align: center" > Year: 2001 ,month: 12 </ h2 >

            < h3 style = "text-align: center" > Total price: 100 </ h3 >

               </ header > "
```

how can I paste it like this?

```
 "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body><header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to format your Html online and convert it into single line format

Use

Www.textfilter.com

And also **convert double inverted commas to single inverted commas**

Secondly when u use it in visual studio , if putting it in string variable u need to add `@` behind your string

```
string myhtmlstring = @"myanyhtmtags";
```

This will prevent escaping and will work